# How do I get the desktop notifications?

Tags: gnome3, notifications

I want to display my desktop notifications (I'm using Gnome 3) on some other device. So I want to write a software that gets the notification on my computer and sends it over the internet. Unfortunately, I didn't find any good point to start on how my code can get the notifications and do something with them.

Is there some API for it?

Comment: This is a little confusing for me.  Are you asking about [how to change the location of gnome notifications](http://askubuntu.com/questions/676475/how-do-i-change-the-location-of-gnome-shell-notifications) or just how to send desktop notification from your own programs?  (or both?)

Comment: @grochmal I clarified it. I want to write a software that reads the notifications on my computer and sends them via network to some other device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, Gnome notifications use D-BUS to pass the messages around.  The [gnome specification](https://developer.gnome.org/notification-spec/) describes how to use the `org.freedesktop.Notifications.*` classes and has a good deal of formatting tips.  In general it is a HTML-ish format.

Yet, you absolutely cannot talk to the D-BUS on another machine remotely.  Let's not even start on how many security holes that would open.

Still, you can always have a program on the target machine that will receive the communication and talk to D-BUS locally already in there.

There are two options that are wrappers around `org.freedesktop.Notifications.*` and make writing programs much easier:

- `libnotify`: which is almost a de-facto standard for making notifications, supports not only gnome but several others.
- `notify-sharp-3`: as strange as it may sound it is an open-source C# based functionality around several notification specs.  At some point it even had its own language called `boo`, but it is kind of dying out in favour of `libnotify`.

OK, `libnotify` we go.

`libnotify` comes with a binary that knows how to talk with the notification daemon (yes, those notifications are displayed by a background daemon).  The command is `notify-send`, and it is rather trivial to use.

```
notify-send 'Meeting in 5 minutes' 'John from the <b>QA Team</b> just found a bug that should never had happened.  Seriously, we are doing something wrong'
```

And that will display the notification.  Yet, making it remote is a little more complex.  Assuming that you know that `bob` is the user currently running Xorg at machine `krakatoa` and that krakatoa has libnotify installed and is running gnome notify daemon you can do:

```
ssh bob@krakatoa \
    notify-send 'Meeting in 5 minutes' \
    'John from the <b>QA Team</b> just found a bug that should never had happened.  Seriously, we are doing something wrong'
```

But finding each user on each machine may be tricky.  You may try to create a script that will perform `ps -afe | grep gnome`, find the user and run `su -u <user> DISPLAY=:0 notify-send ...`.  But then again, you probably should not send `ssh` requests as `root` in the first place.

The [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Desktop_notifications) has a list of interfaces to `libnotify` in several languages.  From there you can create your own daemon, with your own communication protocol for the notification messages.  For example, since you are specifically after gnome, `python Gobject` may just fit the bill.

In summary:

- Notifications happen on D-BUS;
- You cannot directly access D-BUS remotely;
- You can use `libnotify` to access D-BUS from a program under your control on the target machine.

References:

- [Gnome notifications specification](https://developer.gnome.org/notification-spec/)
- [Arch wiki on desktop notifications, with examples using several languages](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Desktop_notifications)

Comment: If daemon is running as root, it does not have access to dbus. Is there any fix in libnotify-dev(c++ implementation) to send notification from root to all the users.

Comment: @vkg by definition there is none.  If you want to interact between users the onus of writing the software is on you. Notably, if you want a channel between a user and a daemon running as root is is a particularly dangerous endeavor and needs very careful - and documented - behaviour on the decisions you took about the communication.  No library will ever take on that, and if a library will no one in their sane mind will use it.

Comment: In case it's not obvious, it has the name `libnotify-bin` on some package managers. For example, on Debian it's `sudo apt install libnotify-bin`